Angular 17 SSR, detect component output event subscribed or not
Using Angular 17 SSR, developing a toolbar component, which carries action button. This is a generic button. Here Im trying to detect component output event are observed or not, depending which buttons a getting displayed.
Is below code valid or not?
<div class="flex flex-row gap-4 justify-between items-center align-middle p-3 bg-[#FFFFFF]">
    <div *ngIf="toolbarType==1 && this.newEvent.observed">
        <button (click)="addClick($event)" class="btn-primary btn-success btn-sm">
            <i class="icofont-plus"></i>
            <span class="">new</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

In the above, toolbarType==1 && this.newEvent.observed here, when new event is attached new button is getting displayed otherwise is not getting displayed. Is this right approach
typescript
import { CommonModule, isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, EventEmitter, Inject, Input, OnInit, Output, output, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { ToolbarAction } from '../../model/enumToolbar';


@Component({
  selector: 'erp-toolbar',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,

  ],
  templateUrl: './toolbar.component.html',
  styleUrl: './toolbar.component.css'
})
export class ToolbarComponent implements OnInit {


  @Input("toolbar") toolbarType!: ToolbarAction;

  @Output("newevent") newEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();


  constructor() {  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }
  addClick = (args: any) => {
    this.newEvent.emit(args);
  }
}


Here we will not get the button displayed, which is explained in my bottom section. The alternative solution to this is.
We create another event using @Input, here we pass the callback that we want to execute. We can also make the input mandatory if needed using @Input({ required: true }) clickEvent!: any;
this will ensure that the button is shown only when event is passed and the event is executed successfully on click.
To make the event execute on the parent context (this) we use bind like [clickEvent]="test.bind(this)"
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule, isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import {
  Component,
  EventEmitter,
  Inject,
  Input,
  OnInit,
  Output,
  output,
  PLATFORM_ID,
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'erp-toolbar',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
  <div class="flex flex-row gap-4 justify-between items-center align-middle p-3 bg-[#FFFFFF]">
    asdf
      <div *ngIf="toolbarType==1 && clickEvent">
          <button (click)="addClick($event)" class="btn-primary btn-success btn-sm">
              <i class="icofont-plus"></i>
              <span class="">new</span>
          </button>
      </div>
  </div>
  `,
})
export class ToolbarComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('toolbar') toolbarType!: any;
  @Input({ required: true }) clickEvent!: any;

  @Output('newevent') newEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor() {
    // this.newEvent.subscribe(); <- shows only when this line is uncommented
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}
  addClick = (args: any) => {
    this.clickEvent(args);
  };
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ToolbarComponent],
  template: `
    <erp-toolbar [clickEvent]="test.bind(this)" [toolbar]="1"/>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  test(e: any) {
    alert('asdf');
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

The observed is set to true only when you manually subscribe to the event emitter in the ts file.
Which is not what I see in the code, so the button will not be displayed.
Instead toggle the button with a flag passed as @Input.
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule, isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import {
  Component,
  EventEmitter,
  Inject,
  Input,
  OnInit,
  Output,
  output,
  PLATFORM_ID,
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'erp-toolbar',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
  <div class="flex flex-row gap-4 justify-between items-center align-middle p-3 bg-[#FFFFFF]">
    asdf
      <div *ngIf="toolbarType==1 && this.newEvent.observed">
          <button (click)="addClick($event)" class="btn-primary btn-success btn-sm">
              <i class="icofont-plus"></i>
              <span class="">new</span>
          </button>
      </div>
  </div>
  `,
})
export class ToolbarComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('toolbar') toolbarType!: any;

  @Output('newevent') newEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor() {
    // this.newEvent.subscribe(); <- shows only when this line is uncommented
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}
  addClick = (args: any) => {
    this.newEvent.emit(args);
  };
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ToolbarComponent],
  template: `
    <erp-toolbar (newEvent)="test($event)" [toolbar]="1"/>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  test(e: any) {

  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

This is also way for detecting the event is assigned or not but my doubt is other button events are not mentioned those buttons should not be visible DOM. let me try this solution
